# Access - Split Field by Character

Tags: vba, ms-access, macros

I have an access table that is currently only 1 field, but it should be 5 separate fields. The field is text and should be split at each ";". Each section between the semicolons can be a different length.

I'm currently creating this table with a macro, so it would be great to be able to add this solution via macro. BUT I am willing to use a function within a query if that's the only option.

Example:
Now:
F1
00584698878941;HG1D100037;HG-G8;HG1D100037;HG-45

Should be:
F1
00584698878941

F2
HG1D100037

F3
HG-G8

F4
HG1D100037

F5
HG-45

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do this with an update query - but it would mean lots of function calls

Here's some code that will work for you:

> **PREP:** Make sure your table has F1, F2, F3, F4, F5 fields
>
> Use "Ctrl-G" to open VB Editor
>
> Insert Module
>
> Copy/Paste Code

```
Public Sub LoadTable()

    Const YOUR_TABLE_NAME   As String = "Table2"
    Const SQL_UPDATE_DATA   As String = "SELECT * FROM [" & YOUR_TABLE_NAME & "] WHERE F2 Is Null"

    Dim rs          As DAO.Recordset
    Dim strF1Data   As String
    Dim varData     As Variant

    Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(SQL_UPDATE_DATA)
    With rs
        Do Until .EOF
            strF1Data = !F1
            varData = Split(strF1Data, ";")
            If UBound(varData) = 4 Then
                .Edit
                !F1 = varData(0)
                !F2 = varData(1)
                !F3 = varData(2)
                !F4 = varData(3)
                !F5 = varData(4)
                .Update
            End If
            .MoveNext
        Loop
        .Close
    End With

    Set rs = Nothing
End Sub
```

> **PREP:** Modify YOUR_TABLE_NAME constant to match your table name
>
> Press F5 to run it

Pick up a good VBA book - there's lots more you can do

Comment: Thanks dbmitch for the quick response. The code seems to get hung up on:

Comment: Are you going to finish that sentence? Does it stop on a line with an error message?

Comment: Thanks dbmitch for the quick response. The code seems to get hung up on:

Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(SQL_UPDATE_DATA)

which I assume stems from:

Const SQL_UPDATE_DATA   As String = "SELECT * FROM [" & YOUR_TABLE_NAME & " WHERE F2 Is Null"

I updated the "YOUR_TABLE _NAME" with "Compare_Files" and added 4 more fields to the table (F2, F3, F4, F5). 

Also, what would you suggest for a good VBA book? Up to this point I have used youtube and forums to learn and pick up what I need when I get stuck.

Comment: Sorry I hit enter trying to space...it seems that it didn't keep the spaces though

Comment: Good pickup - I updated my code - add a right square bracket before " WHERE" in the CONST expression so it looks like `Const SQL_UPDATE_DATA As String = "SELECT * FROM [" & YOUR_TABLE_NAME & "] WHERE F2 Is Null"`

Comment: I'm now getting the error "Too few parameters. Expected 1." I tried pasting the SQL directly into the query, but that didn't seem to do the trick.

Comment: You need to add fields F2, F3, F4, F5 - show me your code and the Table Design screen shot

Answer (score 0):

**To dbmitch:**

**Code:**

'Public Sub LoadTable()

```
Const Compare_Files   As String = "Table2"
Const SQL_UPDATE_DATA As String = "SELECT * FROM [" & Compare_Files & "] WHERE F2 Is Null"


Dim rs          As DAO.Recordset
Dim strF1Data   As String
Dim varData     As Variant

Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(SQL_UPDATE_DATA)
With rs
    Do Until .EOF
        strF1Data = !F1
        varData = Split(strF1Data, ";")
        If UBound(varData) = 4 Then
            .Edit
            !F1 = varData(0)
            !F2 = varData(1)
            !F3 = varData(2)
            !F4 = varData(3)
            !F5 = varData(4)
            .Update
        End If
        .MoveNext
    Loop
    .Close
End With

Set rs = Nothing
```

End Sub`

[Table screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1JNrj.png)

Comment: You're supposed to replace "Table1" with your your table name - not the variable name

Comment: `Const YOUR_TABLE_NAME   As String = "Compare_Files"
Const SQL_UPDATE_DATA As String = "SELECT * FROM [" & YOUR_TABLE_NAME & "] WHERE F2 Is Null"`

Comment: No problem - I should have swapped my variable name with the quoted value - it would have made more sense